# How to call controller method in Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

Good day

I have this `javascript` function below that populates `proposalwaitingapproval`, its loading everything fine but the problem is when I click the edit button:

```
  cell += '<a href="@Url.Action("Create", "Home", new { id = proposal.Id })" class="btn btn-link" style="text-decoration:none">';
            cell += '<i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Edit';
            cell += '</a>';
```

When i click the edit button is does not call the mothod from the controller, here is the url outcome: `http://localhost:61759/@Url.Action(`

```
function PopulateProposalWaitinApprovalTable() {

var table = $('#tblProposalsAwaitingApproval');
abp.ui.setBusy(table);
_proposalService.getWaitingApprovalProposals(true).done(function (data) {

    var receivedData = data;
    var htmlString = '';
    for (var element in data.items) {
        if (data.items.hasOwnProperty(element)) {
            var recievedData = data.items[element];


            var row = '<tr>';
            var cell = '<td style="vertical-align: middle">'+recievedData.id+'</td>';
            cell += '<td style="vertical-align: middle">' + recievedData.application +'</td>';
            cell += '<td style="vertical-align: middle">' + recievedData.dealName + '</td>';
            cell += '<td style="vertical-align: middle">' + recievedData.dealCompanyName + '</td>';
            cell += '<td style="vertical-align: middle">' + recievedData.contactFullName + '</td>';
            cell += '<td style="vertical-align: middle">' + recievedData.creationDate + '</td>';
            cell += '<td style="vertical-align: middle">' + recievedData.lastUpdatedDate + '</td>';
            cell += '<td>';
            if (!recievedData.isApproved)
            {
                cell += '<a href="@Url.Action("Create", "Home", new { id = recievedData.id })" class="btn btn-link" style="text-decoration:none">';
                cell += '<i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Edit';
                cell += '</a>';
            }
            else
            {             
                //@*<button type="button" class="btn btn-link" id="btnCreateRevision" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#RevisionModal" data-content=@proposal.Id><i class="fa fa-clone" aria-hidden="true"></i> @L("CreateRevision")</button>*@
            }
        cell += '</td>';
        row += cell + '</tr>';

        htmlString += row;
        }

        $('#tblProposalsAwaitingApproval > tbody').append(htmlString);
    }
}).always(function () {
    abp.ui.clearBusy(table);
});
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use Razor syntax in Javascript like that. Remember Razor is just a nice way to output some HTML and is resolved by MVC before it renders the page. Javascript runs after the page is rendered and so any Razor you inject into the page at the point will not get processed.

You have two options here. Either hardcode the URL in the Javascript like Chaminda showed or have a hidden element on your page that you can read the value out of like this:

```
@Html.Hidden("homeUrl", Url.Action("Create", "Home"))
```

Then in your Javascript you can read the value from the page:

```
 cell += '<a href="' + $('#homeUrl').val() + '?id=' + recievedData.id + '" class="btn btn-link" style="text-decoration:none">';
            cell += '<i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Edit';
            cell += '</a>';
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be like this. problem is it executing at client side

```
cell += '<a href="Home/Create/id=recievedData.id" class="btn btn-link" style="text- 
decoration:none">';
        cell += '<i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Edit';
        cell += '</a>';
```